# HTML tags work inside script tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am trying to put this inside a script (I want 50% to be dynamic from an XML file)

```html
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" data-progress-animation="50%" data-appear-animation-delay="20">
```

I made this and it works only for Firefox. Any ideas?

```js
x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
i = document.getElementById("combobox").selectedIndex;
var z = document.getElementById("combobox1").selectedIndex;
var y = document.getElementById("combobox1").options;
var m = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("MFPERS"+y[z].value)[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
var str ='<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" data-progress-animation="';
str += m;
str += '%" data-appear-animation-delay="20">';
document.write(str);
```

Comment: This is a very terrible attempt for DOM manipulation, why don't you just change that one attribute?

Comment: Are you trying to document.write to a closed page?  That isn't going to work.  You should create elements, or do an innerHTML.

Comment: How does it only for work Firefox?

Comment: i ama very new (just a few days learning code)
in firefox it loads ok but in chrome it breaks the page.
@meskobalazs i tried to change only one attribute but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you add an id the progressbar div, you can do the following in a JavaScript function:

```
var progressBar = document.getElementById('myProgressBar');
progressBar.dataset['progress-animation'] = percent + '%';
```

By the way, it is *almost always* is a bad idea to use `document.write()`.

Comment: thanks! what is the right way to get xml data inside a <p> for example?

Comment: E.g. you make a string from your XML, then you get your `p` element with a selector, and put it into with the `textContent` property: `pElement.textContent = xmlString;`

Comment: THANKS!
i cant make your first answer to work. 
in my progressbar div i must add id="myProgressBar" and i must remove data-progress-animation="50%"  ?

Comment: Yes you must add the id, the data attribute does not matter if its there or not.

Comment: and progressBar.dataset creates the data attribute inside my div?

( data-progress-animation="50%").....?

if i replace percent with 50 nothing happens...